# .htaccess add ?amp if url contain ?amp

Tags: .htaccess, amp-html

I would like to add the query-string "?amp" to all url of the page, if that page has "?amp" in the url.

E.G. if i'm in example.com?amp and i have this url link

- home.html
- contact.html
- forum.html

i would that all url will be

- home.html?amp
- contact.html?amp
- forum.html?amp

How i can do in .htaccess? I try this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)?amp(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?amp [L,QSA,R]
```

But dosen't work . Could someone help me?

Comment: what do you mean? if users are already requesting ?amp, how you add the ?amp again?

Comment: EG: i have page /test that have some different url link inside . If i call /test?amp , i want that all url inside the page /test?amp need to add "?amp"in the end

Comment: how do you request this url `/test` but with different url inside?

Comment: EG: the page /test has a menu with different url : /home /advertising /contact. So, if i call /test?amp , the url need to change in :  /home?amp  /advertising?amp  /contact?amp

Comment: it is not in htaccess level. You should change it using frontend or backend script

Comment: i see something similar , but dosen't work. I will wait for other developer that know better .htaccess.